# How to call an API inside a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm working on an Actions on Google chatbot using Dialogflow and Cloud Functions. The runtime is Node.js 6.

Why does this function return the empty string?

```js
function getJSON(url) {
  var json = "";
  var request = https.get(url, function(response) {
    var body = "";
    json = 'response';
    response.on("data", function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
      json = 'chunk';
    });
    response.on("end", function() {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          json = 'JSON.parse(body)';
          return json;
        } catch (error) {
          json = 'Error1';
          return json;
        }
      } else {
        json = 'Error2';
        return json;
      }
    });
  });
  return json;
}
```

This is the intent in which I want to access the json data:

```js
app.intent('test', (conv) => {
conv.user.storage.test = 'no change';
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
var options = {
    uri: 'https://teamtreehouse.com/joshtimonen.json',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (user) {
        conv.user.storage.test = user.name;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        conv.user.storage.test = 'fail';
    });
conv.ask(conv.user.storage.test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `request` module for node.js, I tried my self reproducing your use case and worked fine. The code should be something similar to this:

```js
const request = require('request');

request(url, {json: true}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'fulfillmentText': "Some error"})); }
    console.log(body);
  });
```

Also, you need to add `"request": "2.81.0"` in the `dependencies` section inside your `package.json` file.

Comment: Okay, can you explain how to access the JSON object inside my intent?

Answer (score 0):

The function returns the empty string because `https` sets up a callback function, but the program flow continues to the return statement before the callback is called.

In general, when working with Dialogflow Intent Handlers, you should be returning a Promise instead of using callbacks or events. Look into using [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) instead.

Two clarifying points:

- You **must** return the Promise. Otherwise Dialogflow will assume the Handler has completed. If you return the Promise, it will wait for the Promise to finish.
- Everything you want to send back must be done inside the `then()` block. This includes setting any response. The `then()` block runs after the asynchronous operation (the web API call) completes. So this will have the results of the call, and you can return these results in your call to `conv.ask()`.

So it might look something like this:

```
  return rp(options)
    .then(function (user) {
      conv.add('your name is '+user.name);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      conv.add('something went wrong '+err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand how to access the json data. I have added the code of my test intent to my question.

Comment: Hopefully clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) as well

To install Axios : `npm install axios`

OR

You can add it in `package.json` as a dependency

```
 "dependencies": {
     "axios": "^0.27.2",
  }
```

index.js

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

exports.makeRequest = async (req, res) => {

  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')// Dummy URL
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
  res.status(200).json({
  success:true,
  result:response.data
  })
   
})
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    
    console.log(error);
  })
};
```

OR

```
 const Axios = require("axios");

  exports.makeRequest = async (req, res) => {
  const { data } = await 
  Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    res.status(200).send({data})
 };
```